# Why can't I override onConfigurationChanged?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to override the method *onConfigurationChanged* and I get the error:

*The method onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) of type BaseActivity must override or implement a supertype method*

Here is my BaseActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity 
{
    protected View.OnClickListener mButtonListenerUPP;
    protected View.OnClickListener mButtonListenerALT;
    protected View.OnClickListener mButtonListenerNAV;
    protected View.OnClickListener mButtonListenerHIS;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) 
    {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

A lot of posts on the Internet are saying that I can override this method... Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you got `android.content.res.Configuration` in your import statements? Eclipse can insert imports automatically if you press Ctrl+Shift+O.

If that's missing, the compiler will be unable to recognise that you're legitimately overriding the superclass method and so will throw an error.

Comment: Thx, that was it. Eclipse did not suggest I import that package for some reason =)

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess. SuperNotCalledException.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{      
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); // add this line
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem with the @Override annotation. Are you sure that both methods annotated with @Override are defined in Activity?

If not you have to remove the respective @Override annotation.

Comment: They're both public methods in `Activity`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29